# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined using datatable pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatable, pipeline

I am using Datatable pipeline for generating table. My table has dynamic column means it has no fixed column. The column column number changes with the change of a month. Suppose, during current month the table has 4 column but for november it has 32 columns. When I changes month to november,it gives me `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` this error.

My datatable initilization function:

```
   function monthlyAttendanceStatusDatatableInit(tableIdOrCss, url, columns, sortArr, pageLength, year, month) {
          console.log(columns);
          var param = {
            "responsive": false,
            // "columnDefs": [
            //   {responsivePriority: 1, targets: -1},
            //   {responsivePriority: 2, targets: 0}
            // ],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, 'All']],
            "pageLength": pageLength || 10,
            "iDisplayLength": pageLength || 10,
            //"language": { search: "" },
            "sPaginationType": "simple_numbers", // you can also give here 'simple','simple_numbers','full','full_numbers'
            "oLanguage": {
              "sSearch": "Search:",
              "sProcessing": "Loading..."
            },
            "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
              url: url,
              data: {
                'month': month,
                'year': year
              },
              pages: 2 // number of pages to cache
            }),
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "searching": true,
            // "bPaginate": true,
            // "fnDrawCallback":function(){
            //   if(typeof callBack == 'function'){
            //     callBack();
            //   }
            // },
            "destroy": true,
            "paging": true,
            "retrieve": false,
            "aoColumns": columns,
            "aaSorting": sortArr, //[[ 0, "asc" ],[ 1, "desc" ]] // Sort by first column descending
            // "scrollX": true,
            // "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            //   $(row).attr('id', 'employee-'+data.id);
            // }
          };
          // $(tableIdOrCss).remove();
          var table = $(tableIdOrCss).DataTable(param);
    
          return table;
        }
```

I genrating column using server side data.
Columndefinition function:

```
function getColumnDefinition(year, month) {
      var columns = [
        {"sTitle": "ID", "mData": "e_id", "bSortable": true},
        {"sTitle": "Employee Name", "mData": "employee_name", "bSortable": true},
      ];
      var totalDay = getDayCount(year, month);
      var monthS = month.slice(0, 3);
      for (var i = 1; i <= totalDay; i++) {
        if (i < 10) {
          var date = '0' + i.toString();
        }else {
          var date = i.toString();
        }
        var dateColumn = {"sTitle": date + "-" + monthS, "mData": date, "bSortable": true};
        columns.push(dateColumn);
      }
      return columns;
    }
```

I am unable to find any solution

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, using the Snippet editor `[<>]` or https://jsfiddle.net. Thanks!

Comment: I have done something in datatables forum.
http://live.datatables.net/kujimowo/1/edit

Comment: 1) this code does not work for me 2) you have `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` error because you do not update table column headers on month switch.

Comment: @fahimirfan the live datatable does not work because `"{% url 'attendance:ajax-monthly-attendance-status' %}"` is not resolved well, and tries to get that text as url

Comment: @fahimirfan Please mark correct answers as correct (if they are) using a checkmark https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. I've found the error you have been asking about, so marking the answer as correct would help other users to know this is the solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on DataTable documentation for [destroy()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) method, in the case of column change, you should destroy datatable instance and remove all child nodes of the table element with `jQuery#empty()` call before adding new columns.

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
$('#submit').on( 'click', function () {
    $.getJSON( 'newTable', null, function ( json ) {
        table.destroy();
        $('#myTable').empty(); // empty in case the columns change
 
        table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            columns: json.columns,
            data:    json.rows
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Here it is the working [example](https://jsbin.com/giqodexifa/edit?html,js,output).